# Is it SOLID if a class and another class which is used through composition both have same interfaces?

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns, composition, solid-principles

I have the following code where I have an **EnvalidValidator** class that implements an **IEnvironmentVariableValidator** interface

```
import { cleanEnv, port, str } from "envalid";

import IEnvironmentVariableValidator from "../Interfaces/EnvironmentVariableValidator";

class EnvalidValidator implements IEnvironmentVariableValidator {
  validate(env: NodeJS.ProcessEnv) {
    cleanEnv(env, {
      API_PORT: port(),

      DATABASE_TYPE: str(),
      DATABASE_HOST: str(),
      DATABASE_USERNAME: str(),
      DATABASE_PORT: port(),
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: str(),
      DATABASE_NAME: str(),

      NODE_ENV: str(),
    });
  }
}

export default EnvalidValidator;
```

and another class called **EnvironmentVariableValidator** that has an instance of **IEnvironmentVariableValidator** injected into it through its constructor.

```
import IEnvironmentVariableValidator from "../Interfaces/EnvironmentVariableValidator";

class EnvironmentVariableValidator implements IEnvironmentVariableValidator {
  validator: IEnvironmentVariableValidator;

  constructor(validator: IEnvironmentVariableValidator) {
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  validate(env: NodeJS.ProcessEnv) {
    this.validator.validate(env);
  }
}

export default EnvironmentVariableValidator;
```

My question is, is it following clean code, SOLID and is the correct way to make **EnvalidValidator** encapsulation?

Comment: If a class only has 1 useful method (validate), it should probably just be a function. Impossible to say if this makes sense generally because right now `IEnvironmentVariableValidator` does nothing useful.

Comment: @Evert I want to use OOP in this project, no exported functions

Comment: Nothing in solid prevents you from having multiple implementations of an interface, that's simply inheritance, and delegation is a common oop pattern that can be useful in some scenarios. But I don't see why `EnvironmentVariableValidator` exists because it adds no apparent value like composition or adaptation and the injected validator would be equally as good as that class but if you have a reason for it, I'd have no objections

Comment: @zapl the main reason is somewhat hypothetical, if someday `envalid` package becomes deprecated I would just create a new object with another envalid-a-like package and use it in `EnvironmentVariableValidator` instead of deprecated `EnvalidValidator`

Comment: You shouldn't use the class but the interface in any code that requires a validator. (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/401769/depend-on-abstractions-not-on-concretions-what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-this-t ) but it's sometimes tricky in typescript because interface don't exist at runtime and sometime you need a class for e.g. dependency injection framworks

Comment: This is completely over-engineered then. Tons of code that you never need, adds cognitive overhead when it could *literally* be 1 function. You lose *nothing*.

Comment: There's no apparent SOLID violation here. However it doesn't mean the design is right. Naming is everything and it's not clear to me what's the responsibility of `EnvalidValidator ` vs `EnvironmentVariableValidator`. It's also generally a code smell to have a class named exactly after the interface.